# BindingSource.EndEdit() doesn't write values to datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I had hoped that the EndEdit() method would take all bindings and write the control values values back to the datasource. Suprisingly, it doesn't always work. Sometimes the values are not written back to the datasource.

When I want to ensure that the controls write their data back to the datasource, is my only option to get each control's databinding and call WriteValue()?

Any other thoughts or ideas?

**UPDATE**

I bind to an object.
I have a textbox and I handle the TextChanged event. Within this handler I call EndEdit().
When I bind to the datasource, the TextChanged event is called which triggers the EndEdit(). If I then type into the textbox, the FIRST call to EndEdit() has no effect. After that it seems to work.
Note: I can get this to work if I do not have a TextChanged handler until AFTER the data is bound to the TextBox. It seems that the first EndEdit call (during the binding) seems to have a bad effect.

Comment: can you show how you populate your binding source, what is the database engine, how you bind to UI controls and how you are calling the EndEdit ?

Answer (score 0):

EndEdit() only works if binding source is in editing state, which is usually triggered by entering into control or starting actual editing.

Comment: Interesting. How can I find out if a binding source is in the editing state?